# How to filter out values from a pandas data frame for which only one occurrence exists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame with the following columns and values

```
  Temp  Time grain_size
0 335.0 25.0 14.8
1 335.0 30.0 18.7
2 335.0 35.0 22.1
3 187.6 25.0 9.8
4 227.0 25.0 14.2
5 227.0 30.0 16.2
6 118.5 25.0 8.7
```

The data frame given the variable name `df` that has three distinct value which are `335.0`, `187.6`, `227.0`, and `118.5`; however, the values `187.6` and `118.5` only occur once.  I would like to filter the data frame such that it gets rid of values that only occur once so the final data frame looks like.

```
  Temp  Time grain_size
0 335.0 25.0 14.8
1 335.0 30.0 18.7
2 335.0 35.0 22.1
4 227.0 25.0 14.2
5 227.0 30.0 16.2
```

Obviously in this simple case I know the values that only occur once and I can simply user a filtering function to weed them out.  However, I would like to automate the process so that Python will determine which values only occur once and autonomously filter them.  How can I enable this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `duplicated`

```
df[df.Temp.duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[630]: 
    Temp  Time  grain_size
0  335.0  25.0        14.8
1  335.0  30.0        18.7
2  335.0  35.0        22.1
4  227.0  25.0        14.2
5  227.0  30.0        16.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['count']=df.groupby(['Temp']).transform(pd.Series.count)
df = df[df['count']>1]
df.drop(['count'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `dict`

This is a `dict` approach to the same thing done by [WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57078727/2336654)

```
seen = {}
for t in df.Temp:
    seen[t] = t in seen

df[df.Temp.map(seen)]

    Temp  Time  grain_size
0  335.0  25.0        14.8
1  335.0  30.0        18.7
2  335.0  35.0        22.1
4  227.0  25.0        14.2
5  227.0  30.0        16.2
```